# Expected behavior after relocating <img> from <picture> element?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have some HTML with a `<picture>` element that loads a WebP URL if possible and falls back to a jpeg:

```
<div id='placeA'>
</div>

<div id='placeB'>
  <picture>
    <source type="image/webp" 
            srcset="http://www.wpclipart.com/animals/bugs/butterfly/butterfly_4/Monarch_butterfly_USGS.webp">
    <img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/9cz/MMn/9czMMnpcE.jpeg" alt="A butterfly.">
  </picture>
</div>
```

Using javascript, I remove the `<img>` element from the `<picture>` element and place it in 'placeA':

```
document.getElementById('placeA').appendChild(
    document.querySelector('picture img'));
```

However, the image still shows the WebP variant in Chrome. I thought that removing the image from the picture element separates the image from the source set, but apparently not. Is this behavior aligned with the W3C spec?

Fiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cqhfpcew/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. The answer is almost certainly not, if only because the behaviour would be surprising. It's not easy to pin down exactly what the spec says on this, but the [`<img>` element's description](http://w3c.github.io/html/semantics-embedded-content.html#the-img-element) says that the image must [update the image data](http://w3c.github.io/html/semantics-embedded-content.html#update-the-image-data) whenever various DOM mutation events occur, one of which is called out as ["The element is inserted into or removed from a picture parent element."](http://w3c.github.io/html/semantics-embedded-content.html#ref-for-document-inserted-into-the-document-5) which is your test case. So this appears to be a Chrome bug.

Comment: Seems reasonable, thanks! But then, the [selected source technically changes after an image is added to a picture element](http://w3c.github.io/html/semantics-embedded-content.html#update-the-image-data) ... arg, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the issue here that you are not removing the image from the `picture` tag but only copying a reference to it into another page element `#placeA`?

Something like this may be needed...

```
// references to on-page elements
var placeA = document.getElementById('placeA');
var pictureIMG = document.querySelector('picture img');

// save image file location into a variable
var pictureIMGsrc = pictureIMG.src;

// create a image element with this src
var newIMG = document.createElement('img');
newIMG.src = pictureIMGsrc;

// remove image from picture tag
pictureIMG.parentNode.removeChild(pictureIMG);

// add image to #placeA element
placeA.appendChild(newIMG);
```